# Prompt of input function including variables

Tags: python, variables, input

I have the following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
name1 = input('Enter the name of first person ')
name2 = input('Enter the name of second person ')
age1 = int(input("Enter the first age "))
age2 = int(input('Enter the second age '))

print('%s' %name1,  'is %d' %age1, 'years and %s' %name2,  'is %d' %age2, 'years')

agex = age1

age1 = age2
age2 = agex


print('Now we swap ages: %s' %name1,  'is %d' %age1, 'years and %s' %name2,  'is %d' %age2, 'years')
```

What I'd want is to ask for ages including the name entering in the name questions, I mean, something like:

```
age1 = int(input("Enter the age of", name1))
```

But that does not work...

So if you answer as first personame John, so you should get:

> Enter the age of John:

How can I do that?

Comment: Please make your question consistent ... your variables are `name1`, yet you then talk about `nom1`.

Comment: Did you try using `+` instead of `,`?

Comment: Or the `%` formatting you demonstrated that you already know about.

Comment: Off topic, but to swap variables you can use `age1, age2 = age2, age1`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, my question was specific to input function, you're right that I already know about "% formatting" but I've tried something wrong, perhaps. I think that answers are quite useful for other people. But feel free to do what you want :)

Comment: "The answers are quite useful"? They're all present in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
age1 = int(input("Enter the age of {}:".format(name1)))
```

or if you prefer string interpolation:

```
age1 = int(input("Enter the age of %s:" % name1))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` takes a string as its parameter so just create a string with your variable. ie, if `firstname == 'John'`:

```
lastname = input('What is the last name of '+firstname+': ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
age1 = int(input("Enter the first age " + name1))
```

You need to concatenate the strings.  You were so close ...